# Incrementing using a for loop in Groovy

Tags: html, groovy

I want to do use for loop in list of groovy , and print the number of i in table .How can I do this with groovy?

```
 <tr>
     <td>Options</td>
     <td>
     #{list i=0 ,items: optionitem, as:'optionitem' , i++}
     <td> i </td>
     <td>${optionitem}</td>
     <td>
     #{/list} 
   </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using Grails?

Comment: what relevance has the [javascript] tag here?

Comment: Please provide some more context so that we know what environment you are in, what you are trying to achieve etc.

Comment: Clarified title

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Grails...

```
<tr>
    <td>Options</td>
    <td>
    <g:each in="${options}" var="optionitem" status="i" >
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td>${optionitem}</td>
    </g:each>
    </td>
</tr>
```